# java.io.StreamCorruptedException: invalid type code: 4C - replicationstream tomcat

Tags: java, tomcat, serialization

I have following code
The function writes objects to the replicationstream provided by tomcat. IF the object is not serializable then I am trying to write "Misssing value".

```
public void writeExternal(ObjectOutput out)
      throws IOException
    {
      out.writeInt(getType());
      out.writeInt(getAction());
      out.writeUTF(getName());
      out.writeBoolean(getValue()!=null);
      try
      {
          out.writeObject(getValue());
      }
      catch (Exception e)
      {
          System.out.println("Missing Value");

      }

    }
```

Following code reads object. Similar to read if the object is not serializable I try to read again to get read "Missing Value"

```
   public void readExternal(ObjectInput in)
      throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException
    {
      this.type = in.readInt();
      this.action = in.readInt();
      this.name = in.readUTF();    


       boolean hasValue=in.readBoolean();

        try{
             this.value = in.readObject();
        }
        catch(Exception er)
        {
            System.out.println("Missing Value");

        }    

    }
```

I am getting following error, and I am not quite sure what does it mean. Both of the functions are being called for multiple times. First the writeExternal function is called for all the objects and then the readExternal.

```
java.io.StreamCorruptedException: invalid type code: 4C
at java.io.ObjectInputStream$BlockDataInputStream.readBlockHeader(ObjectInputStream.java:2480)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream$BlockDataInputStream.refill(ObjectInputStream.java:2515)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream$BlockDataInputStream.read(ObjectInputStream.java:2587)
at java.io.DataInputStream.readInt(DataInputStream.java:387)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream$BlockDataInputStream.readInt(ObjectInputStream.java:2792)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readInt(ObjectInputStream.java:967)
```

**EDIT**
**Here is the code**

```
public class DeltaRequest
  implements Externalizable
{
  private LinkedList actions = new LinkedList();
  private LinkedList actionPool = new LinkedList();

  public void readExternal(ObjectInput in)
    throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException
  {   
      AttributeInfo info = null;
      if (this.actionPool.size() > 0) {

          info = (AttributeInfo)this.actionPool.removeFirst();      

          info.readExternal(in);
          this.actions.addLast(info);
    }
  }

  public void writeExternal(ObjectOutput out)
    throws IOException
  {

    out.writeUTF(getSessionId());
    out.writeBoolean(this.recordAllActions);
    out.writeInt(getSize());
    for (int i = 0; i < getSize(); i++) {
      AttributeInfo info = (AttributeInfo)this.actions.get(i);
      info.writeExternal(out);


    }
  }

  protected byte[] serialize()
    throws IOException
  {

    ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(bos);
    writeExternal(oos);
    oos.flush();
    oos.close();
    return bos.toByteArray();
  }

  private static class AttributeInfo implements Externalizable {
    private String name = null;
    private Object value = null;
    private int action;
    private int type;

    public AttributeInfo() {
    }

    public AttributeInfo(int type, int action, String name, Object value) {
      init(type, action, name, value);
    }

    public void init(int type, int action, String name, Object value)
    {
      this.name = name;
      this.value = value;
      this.action = action;
      this.type = type;
    }

    public int getType() {
      return this.type;
    }

    public int getAction() {
      return this.action;
    }

    public Object getValue() {
      return this.value;
    }
    public int hashCode() {
      return this.name.hashCode();
    }

    public String getName() {
      return this.name;
    }

    public void recycle() {
      this.name = null;
      this.value = null;
      this.type = -1;
      this.action = -1;
    }

    public boolean equals(Object o) {
      if (!(o instanceof AttributeInfo)) return false;
      AttributeInfo other = (AttributeInfo)o;
      return other.getName().equals(getName());
    }

    public void readExternal(ObjectInput in)
      throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException
    {
      this.type = in.readInt();
      this.action = in.readInt();
      this.name = in.readUTF();

      boolean hasValue=in.readBoolean();

      try{
         this.value = in.readObject();
      }
      catch(Exception er)
      {
         out.writeObject("Value Missing");
      }


    }

    public void writeExternal(ObjectOutput out)
      throws IOException
    {
      out.writeInt(getType());
      out.writeInt(getAction());
      out.writeUTF(getName());
      out.writeBoolean(getValue()!=null);
      try
      {
          out.writeObject(getValue());
      }
      catch (Exception e)
      {
          out.writeObject("Value Missing");
      }
    }

    public String toString()
    {
      StringBuffer buf = new StringBuffer("AttributeInfo[type=");
      buf.append(getType()).append(", action=").append(getAction());
      buf.append(", name=").append(getName()).append(", value=").append(getValue());
      buf.append(", addr=").append(super.toString()).append("]");
      return buf.toString();
    }
  }
}
```

Code:
This is how the above function are called.

```
protected DeltaRequest deserializeDeltaRequest(DeltaSession objbb, byte[] data)
    throws ClassNotFoundException, IOException
  {
    try
    {
      objbb.lock();
      ReplicationStream ois = getReplicationStream(data);
      objbb.getDeltaRequest().readExternal(ois);
      ois.close();
      return objbb.getDeltaRequest();
    } finally {
      objbb.unlock();
    }
  }

  protected byte[] serializeDeltaRequest(DeltaSession objbb, DeltaRequest objAA)
    throws IOException
  {
    try
    {
      objbb.lock();
      return objAA.serialize();
    } finally {
      objbb.unlock();
    }
  }
```

DeltaManager

```
public class DeltaManager extends ClusterManagerBase
{




  public Session createSession(String sessionId)
  {
    return createSession(sessionId, true);
  }

  public Session createSession(String sessionId, boolean distribute)
  {
    if ((this.maxActiveSessions >= 0) && (this.sessions.size() >= this.maxActiveSessions)) {
      this.rejectedSessions += 1;
      throw new IllegalStateException(sm.getString("deltaManager.createSession.ise"));
    }
    DeltaSession session = (DeltaSession)super.createSession(sessionId);
    if (distribute) {
      sendCreateSession(session.getId(), session);
    }
    if (log.isDebugEnabled())
      log.debug(sm.getString("deltaManager.createSession.newSession", session.getId(), new Integer(this.sessions.size())));
    return session;
  }

  protected void sendCreateSession(String sessionId, DeltaSession session)
  {
    if (this.cluster.getMembers().length > 0) {
      SessionMessage msg = new SessionMessageImpl(getName(), 1, null, sessionId, sessionId + "-" + System.currentTimeMillis());

      if (log.isDebugEnabled()) log.debug(sm.getString("deltaManager.sendMessage.newSession", this.name, sessionId));
      msg.setTimestamp(session.getCreationTime());
      this.counterSend_EVT_SESSION_CREATED += 1L;
      send(msg);
    }
  }


  protected DeltaRequest deserializeDeltaRequest(DeltaSession session, byte[] data)
    throws ClassNotFoundException, IOException
  {
    try
    {
      session.lock();
      ReplicationStream ois = getReplicationStream(data);
      session.getDeltaRequest().readExternal(ois);
      ois.close();
      return session.getDeltaRequest();
    } finally {
      session.unlock();
    }
  }

  protected byte[] serializeDeltaRequest(DeltaSession session, DeltaRequest deltaRequest)
    throws IOException
  {
    try
    {
      session.lock();
      return deltaRequest.serialize();
    } finally {
      session.unlock();
    }
  }

  protected void deserializeSessions(byte[] data)
    throws ClassNotFoundException, IOException
  {
    ClassLoader originalLoader = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader();
    ObjectInputStream ois = null;
    try
    {
      ois = getReplicationStream(data);
      Integer count = (Integer)ois.readObject();
      int n = count.intValue();
      for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        DeltaSession session = (DeltaSession)createEmptySession();
        session.readObjectData(ois);
        session.setManager(this);
        session.setValid(true);
        session.setPrimarySession(false);

        session.access();

        session.setAccessCount(0);
        session.resetDeltaRequest();

        if (findSession(session.getIdInternal()) == null) {
          this.sessionCounter += 1;
        } else {
          this.sessionReplaceCounter += 1L;

          if (log.isWarnEnabled()) log.warn(sm.getString("deltaManager.loading.existing.session", session.getIdInternal()));
        }
        add(session);
      }
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
      log.error(sm.getString("deltaManager.loading.cnfe", e), e);
      throw e;
    } catch (IOException e) {
      log.error(sm.getString("deltaManager.loading.ioe", e), e);
      throw e;
    }
    finally {
      try {
        if (ois != null) ois.close(); 
      }
      catch (IOException f)
      {
      }
      ois = null;
      if (originalLoader != null) Thread.currentThread().setContextClassLoader(originalLoader);
    }
  }

  protected byte[] serializeSessions(Session[] currentSessions)
    throws IOException
  {
    ByteArrayOutputStream fos = null;
    ObjectOutputStream oos = null;
    try
    {
      fos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
      oos = new ObjectOutputStream(new BufferedOutputStream(fos));
      oos.writeObject(new Integer(currentSessions.length));
      for (int i = 0; i < currentSessions.length; i++) {
        ((DeltaSession)currentSessions[i]).writeObjectData(oos);
      }

      oos.flush();
    } catch (IOException e) {
      log.error(sm.getString("deltaManager.unloading.ioe", e), e);
      throw e;
    } finally {
      if (oos != null) {
        try {
          oos.close();
        }
        catch (IOException f) {
        }
        oos = null;
      }
    }

    return fos.toByteArray();
  }

  public void start()
    throws LifecycleException
  {
    if (!this.initialized) init();

    if (this.started) {
      return;
    }
    this.started = true;
    this.lifecycle.fireLifecycleEvent("start", null);

    generateSessionId();
    try
    {
      Cluster cluster = getCluster();

      if (cluster == null) {
        Container context = getContainer();
        if ((context != null) && ((context instanceof Context))) {
          Container host = context.getParent();
          if ((host != null) && ((host instanceof Host))) {
            cluster = host.getCluster();
            if ((cluster != null) && ((cluster instanceof CatalinaCluster))) {
              setCluster((CatalinaCluster)cluster);
            } else {
              Container engine = host.getParent();
              if ((engine != null) && ((engine instanceof Engine))) {
                cluster = engine.getCluster();
                if ((cluster != null) && ((cluster instanceof CatalinaCluster)))
                  setCluster((CatalinaCluster)cluster);
              }
              else {
                cluster = null;
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
      if (cluster == null) {
        log.error(sm.getString("deltaManager.noCluster", getName()));
        return;
      }
      if (log.isInfoEnabled()) {
        String type = "unknown";
        if ((cluster.getContainer() instanceof Host))
          type = "Host";
        else if ((cluster.getContainer() instanceof Engine)) {
          type = "Engine";
        }
        log.info(sm.getString("deltaManager.registerCluster", getName(), type, cluster.getClusterName()));
      }

      if (log.isInfoEnabled()) log.info(sm.getString("deltaManager.startClustering", getName()));

      cluster.registerManager(this);

      getAllClusterSessions();
    }
    catch (Throwable t) {
      log.error(sm.getString("deltaManager.managerLoad"), t);
    }
  }

  public synchronized void getAllClusterSessions()
  {
    if ((this.cluster != null) && (this.cluster.getMembers().length > 0)) {
      long beforeSendTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
      Member mbr = findSessionMasterMember();
      if (mbr == null) {
        return;
      }
      SessionMessage msg = new SessionMessageImpl(getName(), 4, null, "GET-ALL", "GET-ALL-" + getName());

      this.stateTransferCreateSendTime = beforeSendTime;

      this.counterSend_EVT_GET_ALL_SESSIONS += 1L;
      this.stateTransfered = false;
      try
      {
        synchronized (this.receivedMessageQueue) {
          this.receiverQueue = true;
        }
        this.cluster.send(msg, mbr);
        if (log.isWarnEnabled()) log.warn(sm.getString("deltaManager.waitForSessionState", getName(), mbr, Integer.valueOf(getStateTransferTimeout())));

        waitForSendAllSessions(beforeSendTime);
      } finally {
        synchronized (this.receivedMessageQueue) {
          for (Iterator iter = this.receivedMessageQueue.iterator(); iter.hasNext(); ) {
            SessionMessage smsg = (SessionMessage)iter.next();
            if (!this.stateTimestampDrop) {
              messageReceived(smsg, smsg.getAddress() != null ? smsg.getAddress() : null);
            }
            else if ((smsg.getEventType() != 4) && (smsg.getTimestamp() >= this.stateTransferCreateSendTime))
            {
              messageReceived(smsg, smsg.getAddress() != null ? smsg.getAddress() : null);
            }
            else if (log.isWarnEnabled()) {
              log.warn(sm.getString("deltaManager.dropMessage", getName(), smsg.getEventTypeString(), new Date(this.stateTransferCreateSendTime), new Date(smsg.getTimestamp())));
            }

          }

          this.receivedMessageQueue.clear();
          this.receiverQueue = false;
        }
      }
    }
    else if (log.isInfoEnabled()) { log.info(sm.getString("deltaManager.noMembers", getName())); }

  }

  protected void registerSessionAtReplicationValve(DeltaSession session)
  {
    if ((this.replicationValve == null) && 
      ((this.container instanceof StandardContext)) && (((StandardContext)this.container).getCrossContext())) {
      Cluster cluster = getCluster();
      if ((cluster != null) && ((cluster instanceof CatalinaCluster))) {
        Valve[] valves = ((CatalinaCluster)cluster).getValves();
        if ((valves != null) && (valves.length > 0)) {
          for (int i = 0; (this.replicationValve == null) && (i < valves.length); i++) {
            if ((valves[i] instanceof ReplicationValve)) this.replicationValve = ((ReplicationValve)valves[i]);
          }

          if ((this.replicationValve == null) && (log.isDebugEnabled())) {
            log.debug("no ReplicationValve found for CrossContext Support");
          }
        }
      }
    }

    if (this.replicationValve != null)
      this.replicationValve.registerReplicationSession(session);
  }

  protected Member findSessionMasterMember()
  {
    Member mbr = null;
    Member[] mbrs = this.cluster.getMembers();
    if (mbrs.length != 0) mbr = mbrs[0];
    if ((mbr == null) && (log.isWarnEnabled())) log.warn(sm.getString("deltaManager.noMasterMember", getName(), ""));
    if ((mbr != null) && (log.isDebugEnabled())) log.warn(sm.getString("deltaManager.foundMasterMember", getName(), mbr));
    return mbr;
  }



  public void messageDataReceived(ClusterMessage cmsg)
  {
    if ((cmsg != null) && ((cmsg instanceof SessionMessage))) {
      SessionMessage msg = (SessionMessage)cmsg;
      switch (msg.getEventType()) {
      case 1:
      case 2:
      case 3:
      case 4:
      case 13:
        synchronized (this.receivedMessageQueue) {
          if (this.receiverQueue) {
            this.receivedMessageQueue.add(msg);
            return;
          }
        }
        break;
      case 5:
      case 6:
      case 7:
      case 8:
      case 9:
      case 10:
      case 11:
      case 12: } messageReceived(msg, msg.getAddress() != null ? msg.getAddress() : null);
    }
  }

  public ClusterMessage requestCompleted(String sessionId)
  {
    return requestCompleted(sessionId, false);
  }

  public ClusterMessage requestCompleted(String sessionId, boolean expires)
  {
    DeltaSession session = null;
    try {
      session = (DeltaSession)findSession(sessionId);
      DeltaRequest deltaRequest = session.getDeltaRequest();
      session.lock();
      msg = null;
      boolean isDeltaRequest = false;
      synchronized (deltaRequest) {
        isDeltaRequest = deltaRequest.getSize() > 0;
        if (isDeltaRequest) {
          this.counterSend_EVT_SESSION_DELTA += 1L;
          byte[] data = serializeDeltaRequest(session, deltaRequest);
          msg = new SessionMessageImpl(getName(), 13, data, sessionId, sessionId + "-" + System.currentTimeMillis());

          session.resetDeltaRequest();
        }
      }
      if (!isDeltaRequest) {
        if ((!expires) && (!session.isPrimarySession())) {
          this.counterSend_EVT_SESSION_ACCESSED += 1L;
          msg = new SessionMessageImpl(getName(), 3, null, sessionId, sessionId + "-" + System.currentTimeMillis());

          if (log.isDebugEnabled()) {
            log.debug(sm.getString("deltaManager.createMessage.accessChangePrimary", getName(), sessionId));
          }
        }
      }
      else if (log.isDebugEnabled()) {
        log.debug(sm.getString("deltaManager.createMessage.delta", getName(), sessionId));
      }

      if (!expires)
        session.setPrimarySession(true);
      long replDelta;
      if ((!expires) && (msg == null)) {
        replDelta = System.currentTimeMillis() - session.getLastTimeReplicated();
        if (replDelta > getMaxInactiveInterval() * 1000) {
          this.counterSend_EVT_SESSION_ACCESSED += 1L;
          msg = new SessionMessageImpl(getName(), 3, null, sessionId, sessionId + "-" + System.currentTimeMillis());

          if (log.isDebugEnabled()) {
            log.debug(sm.getString("deltaManager.createMessage.access", getName(), sessionId));
          }

        }

      }

      if (msg != null) {
        session.setLastTimeReplicated(System.currentTimeMillis());
        msg.setTimestamp(session.getLastTimeReplicated());
      }
      return msg;
    }
    catch (IOException x)
    {
      SessionMessage msg;
      log.error(sm.getString("deltaManager.createMessage.unableCreateDeltaRequest", sessionId), x);
      return null;
    } finally {
      if (session != null) session.unlock();
    }
  }



  protected void messageReceived(SessionMessage msg, Member sender)
  {
    if ((doDomainReplication()) && (!checkSenderDomain(msg, sender))) {
      return;
    }
    ClassLoader contextLoader = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader();
    try
    {
      ClassLoader[] loaders = getClassLoaders();
      if ((loaders != null) && (loaders.length > 0)) Thread.currentThread().setContextClassLoader(loaders[0]);
      if (log.isDebugEnabled()) log.debug(sm.getString("deltaManager.receiveMessage.eventType", getName(), msg.getEventTypeString(), sender));

      switch (msg.getEventType()) {
      case 4:
        handleGET_ALL_SESSIONS(msg, sender);
        break;
      case 12:
        handleALL_SESSION_DATA(msg, sender);
        break;
      case 14:
        handleALL_SESSION_TRANSFERCOMPLETE(msg, sender);
        break;
      case 1:
        handleSESSION_CREATED(msg, sender);
        break;
      case 2:
        handleSESSION_EXPIRED(msg, sender);
        break;
      case 3:
        handleSESSION_ACCESSED(msg, sender);
        break;
      case 13:
        handleSESSION_DELTA(msg, sender);
      case 5:
      case 6:
      case 7:
      case 8:
      case 9:
      case 10:
      case 11:
      }
    } catch (Exception x) { log.error(sm.getString("deltaManager.receiveMessage.error", getName()), x);
    } finally {
      Thread.currentThread().setContextClassLoader(contextLoader);
    }
  }

  protected void handleALL_SESSION_TRANSFERCOMPLETE(SessionMessage msg, Member sender)
  {
    this.counterReceive_EVT_ALL_SESSION_TRANSFERCOMPLETE += 1;
    if (log.isDebugEnabled()) log.debug(sm.getString("deltaManager.receiveMessage.transfercomplete", getName(), sender.getHost(), new Integer(sender.getPort())));
    this.stateTransferCreateSendTime = msg.getTimestamp();
    this.stateTransfered = true;
  }

  protected void handleSESSION_DELTA(SessionMessage msg, Member sender)
    throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException
  {
    this.counterReceive_EVT_SESSION_DELTA += 1L;
    byte[] delta = msg.getSession();
    DeltaSession session = (DeltaSession)findSession(msg.getSessionID());
    if (session != null) {
      if (log.isDebugEnabled()) log.debug(sm.getString("deltaManager.receiveMessage.delta", getName(), msg.getSessionID())); try
      {
        session.lock();
        DeltaRequest dreq = deserializeDeltaRequest(session, delta);
        dreq.execute(session, this.notifyListenersOnReplication);
        session.setPrimarySession(false);
      } finally {
        session.unlock();
      }
    }
  }



  protected void handleSESSION_CREATED(SessionMessage msg, Member sender)
  {
    this.counterReceive_EVT_SESSION_CREATED += 1L;
    if (log.isDebugEnabled()) log.debug(sm.getString("deltaManager.receiveMessage.createNewSession", getName(), msg.getSessionID()));
    DeltaSession session = (DeltaSession)createEmptySession();
    session.setManager(this);
    session.setValid(true);
    session.setPrimarySession(false);
    session.setCreationTime(msg.getTimestamp());

    session.setMaxInactiveInterval(getMaxInactiveInterval());
    session.access();
    if (this.notifySessionListenersOnReplication) {
      session.setId(msg.getSessionID());
    } else {
      session.setIdInternal(msg.getSessionID());
      add(session);
    }
    session.resetDeltaRequest();
    session.endAccess();
  }

  protected void handleALL_SESSION_DATA(SessionMessage msg, Member sender)
    throws ClassNotFoundException, IOException
  {
    this.counterReceive_EVT_ALL_SESSION_DATA += 1L;
    if (log.isDebugEnabled()) log.debug(sm.getString("deltaManager.receiveMessage.allSessionDataBegin", getName()));
    byte[] data = msg.getSession();
    deserializeSessions(data);
    if (log.isDebugEnabled()) log.debug(sm.getString("deltaManager.receiveMessage.allSessionDataAfter", getName()));
  }

  protected void handleGET_ALL_SESSIONS(SessionMessage msg, Member sender)
    throws IOException
  {
    this.counterReceive_EVT_GET_ALL_SESSIONS += 1L;

    if (log.isDebugEnabled()) log.debug(sm.getString("deltaManager.receiveMessage.unloadingBegin", getName()));

    Session[] currentSessions = findSessions();
    long findSessionTimestamp = System.currentTimeMillis();
    if (isSendAllSessions()) {
      sendSessions(sender, currentSessions, findSessionTimestamp);
    }
    else {
      int len = currentSessions.length < getSendAllSessionsSize() ? currentSessions.length : getSendAllSessionsSize();
      Session[] sendSessions = new Session[len];
      for (int i = 0; i < currentSessions.length; i += getSendAllSessionsSize()) {
        len = i + getSendAllSessionsSize() > currentSessions.length ? currentSessions.length - i : getSendAllSessionsSize();
        System.arraycopy(currentSessions, i, sendSessions, 0, len);
        sendSessions(sender, sendSessions, findSessionTimestamp);
        if (getSendAllSessionsWaitTime() > 0)
          try {
            Thread.sleep(getSendAllSessionsWaitTime());
          }
          catch (Exception sleep)
          {
          }
      }
    }
    SessionMessage newmsg = new SessionMessageImpl(this.name, 14, null, "SESSION-STATE-TRANSFERED", "SESSION-STATE-TRANSFERED" + getName());
    newmsg.setTimestamp(findSessionTimestamp);
    if (log.isDebugEnabled()) log.debug(sm.getString("deltaManager.createMessage.allSessionTransfered", getName()));
    this.counterSend_EVT_ALL_SESSION_TRANSFERCOMPLETE += 1;
    this.cluster.send(newmsg, sender);
  }

  protected void sendSessions(Member sender, Session[] currentSessions, long sendTimestamp)
    throws IOException
  {
    byte[] data = serializeSessions(currentSessions);
    if (log.isDebugEnabled()) log.debug(sm.getString("deltaManager.receiveMessage.unloadingAfter", getName()));
    SessionMessage newmsg = new SessionMessageImpl(this.name, 12, data, "SESSION-STATE", "SESSION-STATE-" + getName());
    newmsg.setTimestamp(sendTimestamp);
    if (log.isDebugEnabled()) log.debug(sm.getString("deltaManager.createMessage.allSessionData", getName()));
    this.counterSend_EVT_ALL_SESSION_DATA += 1L;
    this.cluster.send(newmsg, sender);
  }


}
```

Comment: What does the calling code look like? And is this exception thrown from within your `readExternal()` method?

Comment: yes, the exception is thrown from readExternal. I have object called info and readExternal is a part of that class. So I call the function as info.readExternal(in). There are several object of type info, so i have loop to call the function for each of the object.

Comment: I suggest you post the calling code into your answer, including details of when the streams get created.

Comment: I have updated the post with the source code.

Comment: All you've done is *repost* the *same* code. Not the 'calling code', or the 'details of when the streams get created' that I asked for.

Comment: Sigh. You *still* haven't provided the 'details of when the streams get created'. You've also left out the `serialize()` method, which surely qualifies as 'calling code' in this circumstance. But your strategy doesn't seem sound. Instead of writing nothing and catching every possible exception and treating that as 'missing data', surely it would be better to write a null?

Comment: I have updated the code, the seralize function is there in DeltaRequest class. The reason I dont want to write null is that there can be instances where the actual object which I am going to seerialize can be null in that case I need to differentiate between the object which wasnt serializable and the object which was null in itself.

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that you are calling

```
this.writeExternal(oos);
```

instead of

```
oos.writeObject(this);
```

so the `ObjectOutputStream` never gets the chance to write the object preamble.

Similarly, you must call

```
Object o = ois.readObject();
```

rather than

```
Object o = this.readExternal(ois);
```

Re your non-serializable object, you should write a special object. At the moment you are treating every possible exception as just a missing object, when it could be a huge number of other things.